# finally() is not called when returning empty() in catch()

Tags: rxjs5

I wrote a generic request method that is supposed to show a loading indicator while the request is running. If an error occurs (like 404), I display the message in `.catch` and then `return Observable.empty()`, so that the following code doesn't crash (since no data is returned).

The big problem is that then `.finally` won't be called either. Is that a bug? Is there a workaround? Here's my code:

```
res = Observable
  .of(true)
  .do(() => this.store.dispatch(new ShowLoadingIndicatorAction()))
  .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url, { headers: this.headers }))
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount()
  .catch(error => {
    this.messages.handleRequestError(error);
    return Observable.empty();
  })
  .finally(() => this.store.dispatch(new HideLoadingIndicatorAction()));

// then later:
res.subscribe(doStuffWithData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What RxJS-version are you using? It does works fine in this example:

```js
const res$ = Rx.Observable
  .of(true)
  .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.throw("Rest Error"))
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount()
  .catch(error => Rx.Observable.empty())
  .finally(() => console.log("Calling Finally!"));

res$.subscribe(console.info);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gee, you seem to be right! I am using 5.0.3. Seems that showing a message in Ionic blocks the loading indicator... I should have used console.log to test it. Thanks, and sorry :)

Comment: Okay - maybe you can tag the questin with "Ionic" then as well and provide an answer yourself in case someone else stumbles upon the issue :)

Comment: Well, this issue seems not that useful: it turns out our app showed several loading indicators, one of which wasn't closed because the .finally() call was actually missing in that stream. So everything works as intended, the problem was in front of the keyboard....