# How to make execution wait for forkJoin results

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

How can I make the following code wait for `forkJoin` execution so I can return results from `bulkRequest`?

```
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    let results = this.bulkRequest(this.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"),
      this.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"),
      this.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"));

    console.log("results");
  }

  get(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url).map(response => response.json());
  }

  bulkRequest(...sources: SubscribableOrPromise<any>[]): any[] {
    let results: any[];

    Observable.forkJoin(
        sources
    ).subscribe(response => {
        console.log("responses");
        results = response;
    }, error => {
      console.log("error: " + error.toString());
    },
    () => {
      console.log("finally");
    });

    return results;
  }
```

Currently I'm getting the following console output and `results` variable is `undefined`:

```
results
responses
finally
```

The observable do execute, if I put a breakpoint at `console.log("results")` line I see all three of them as `Pending` in Network tab.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2wb72kw7S3wYUUwwwi8h?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return Observable.forkJoin( ...
```

and remove

```
return results;
```

There is no way to wait for observables.
You need to subscribe to the returned observable where you call `bulkRequest()`.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, I need to do something in complete block ((console.log("finally") line) and I rather not do it every time I need to call bulkRequest. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a `finally` operator that you can use instead, and when you mention it, I forgot that you need to change `subscribe` to `map`. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999077/finally-is-not-called-when-returning-empty-in-catch

Answer (score 2):

Return the Observable instead of the `results` variable:

```
public bulkRequest(...sources: SubscribableOrPromise<any>[]): any[] {
  return Observable.forkJoin(sources);
}
```

See your updated demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/7DPBjeha0p2vdj4QjN5V?p=info